# Using location.reload() seems to prevent php from updating db

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, bootbox

Been stumped by this one for a while now, cant figure out what i have done wrong. The following code uses a  bootbox.js button to delete a post on a social network i am working on:

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#post<?php echo $p_id; ?>').on('click', function() {
            bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this post?", function(result) {

                $.post("./includes/form_handlers/delete_post.php?post_id=<?php echo $p_id; ?>", {result:result});
                /*This breaks*/
                //if(result)
                   //location.reload();


            });
        });


    });


    </script>
```

For some reason calling location.reload seems to prevent my php handler from executing an sql statement (it is a simple update query). Oddly enough when it is commented out, the db updates without problems.

Can someone explain this to me and possibly reccomend a solution?

Comment: because it is a race condition between the Ajax call going out and the page reloading... You should reload when the Ajax call is complete.

Answer (score 4):

You have a race between an HTTP Call and the page reloading. The page reload will kill off the http request, it does not wait for it to complete.

So the solution is move the reload line inside of the success callback.

```
$.post("./includes/form_handlers/delete_post.php?post_id=<?php echo $p_id; ?>", {result:result})
  .done( function(){ window.location.reload(true); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `location.reload();` is executing before the ajax call is complete so the ajax call can run until the end.

The correct way would be to wait for the ajax call response and only then do the reload:

```
$.post("./includes/form_handlers/delete_post.php?post_id=<?php echo $p_id; ?>", {result:result}).done(function(){ location.reload(); });
```

More info here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jqxhr-object

Comment: sorry... thought I click on mine to edit. lol... I need more coffee

Comment: np. Did that 1 hour ago too :)

Answer (score 1):

When you call `location.reload`your browser cancels all XHR requests. You should use success callback of `$.post` to reload like below:

```
$.post("./includes/form_handlers/delete_post.php?post_id=<?php echo $p_id; ?>", {result:result})
.done(function( data ) {
    location.reload();
});
```